# Django template tag for form elements

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I have problem with templatetags usage in Django.Let me define my html and template tag.

**photo_detail.html**

```
{% for photo in pList %}
    {% getFormElements form photo.pk %}

    {{ caption_field }}
    {{ city_field }}

{%endfor %}
```

**photohelper.py**

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.inclusion_tag('wpphotos/post/photo_detail.html')
def getFormElements(form,pid):
    return {'caption_field':form.fields['caption_%s' % pid],'country_field':form.fields['country_%s' % pid],'city_field':form.fields['city_%s' % pid] }
```

My form has fields such as

```
caption_1
city_1
country_1
caption_2
city_2
country_2
```

What I want do is grouping `caption,country and city` by photo id while render those fields.

I try to illustrate my aim at the code above but it doesn't work.

How can I achive this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're a little confused about inclusion tags. Inclusion tags don't go inside the template they refer to - they *render* that template. So the `{% getFormElements form photo.pk %}` bit belongs in the main template, then the various fields go in the template that's rendered by the tag.